# Custom Postfix Completion in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Is it possible to make custom "Postfix Completion" in Android studio ?

```
 Settings -> Editor -> Postfix Completion
```

In Eclipse it's called "Template". I just wan't to write shortcut (e.g. rer) and get (e.g android.util.Log.i("customTAG",$cursor);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is `Live template`. It's different of postfix. A bit late but it's already existing as `loge`, `logi` etc...

[image: Live Template Android Studio]